# SendKeys doesn't work in Selenium PhantomJS

Tags: java, selenium, phantomjs, selenium-chromedriver

I made a test for ChromeDriver and it work's good, but i can't use same code with PhantomJS, because of error with "sendKeys":

```
        WebElement login = driver.findElement(By.id("username"));
        login.sendKeys(username);
```

**This is what i get:**

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.UnsupportedCommandException: TypeError - undefined is not a constructor (evaluating '_getTagName(currWindow).toLowerCase()')
```

Comment: Issue regarding this already logged here  https://github.com/detro/ghostdriver/issues/445.

Comment: Can you provide some more information as: 1. Which website are you trying? If it is a public IP can you share the url?

Comment: @Dev Sure, https://www.twitch.tv/login